# How is it possible to find out, which tagged work status changed with WorkManager?

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-workmanager

I would like to call a function, every time a work with a given tag finished. I do it like this:

```
LiveData<List<WorkInfo>> liveData = manager.getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(MY_WORK_TAG);
liveData.observe(owner, new Observer<List<WorkInfo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<WorkInfo> workInfos) {
        Log.i("MyWorkManager", "Infos: " + Integer.toString(workInfos.size()));
        // Which WorkInfo changed??
        /*
        if (workInfo.getState() != null && workInfo.getState() == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            //
        }
        */
    }
});
```

This code is called, but the `workInfos` list contains a lot of items, and I have no idea, which WorkInfo  was changed in the list. It contains info from works, which were completed a long time ago.

Comment: Just iterate over `workInfos` list and find your work using unique id.

Comment: But I dont know the unique id. I only know tha tag name

Comment: Are you likely to see multiple states of the Worker while the Observer is active?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @brwngrldev I just ended up using the commented out code with `workInfo.getState() == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED`